# Best Java Example for Twitter Connecting

Tags: java, twitter

I'm porting a rails app to grails that uses oauth to push messages to Twitter.  Any suggestions for groovy or java examples or opinions on the various libraries mentioned on the twitter site for java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used Twitter4J in the past to develop a Twitter App with pretty good results.  However, I'm not sure how good its OAuth support is.

http://yusuke.homeip.net/twitter4j/en/index.html

Comment: Is there a way to get a users public timeline without you own sign in credentials? I can see Twitter timelines of people without being signed in but I can't see how to do it using this package?